# Using guardian's assign_perm in a south migration

Tags: python, django-south, django-guardian

I can't get django-guardian assign_perm to work in a south datamigration ... the reason it is not working seems to be because guardian is not using the frozen ORM. How can I get other apps in general and django-guardian specifically to use frozen models.

Comment: I ended up using a mixture of orm['contenttypes.ContentType'], orm['auth.permission'], orm['guardian.userobjectpermission'] ... to manually get_or_create permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I used `get_user_model()` instead of `orm['auth.User']`